# Generate error logs for php project in text file

Tags: php

I want to store all Php error like fatal error warnings that are come during execution of our code.I use this code in my Php.ini file:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
log_errors = On
display_errors = Off
error_log = /home/fgdh/public_html/php_error.log
```

Now i don't know why errors are not stored.please help

Comment: make sure /error_logs/ folder have write permission  for apache user

Comment: now i am using error_log = /home/user_name/public_html/php_error.log on FTP but errors are not stored in this.I also checked permissions.

Comment: which server is this ?

find Apache user expected user name is apache2 , www-data , httpd

so you need to run 

chown user:user /home/fgdh/public_html/php_error.log

This will might be solve your problem

Comment: Ok this issue is solved but error_log('any error') this is called every time also if there is no error